# How to delete all edges from Microsoft Azure Cosmos DB if query RU cost exceeds the limit

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

We have a graph in Azure Cosmos DB (Gremlin API) with approx 3K vertices and 16K edges. I would like to drop all edges but keep the vertices.

When I run gremlin query like `q.E().drop()` I get the exception

```
ExceptionType : RequestRateTooLargeException ExceptionMessage : Message: {"Errors":["Request rate is large"]}
```

Current RU/s limit is 3000 RU/s

I understand the mechanism behind throwing such error. 
The "wait and retry" is not an option here - the limit is exceeded by a single query not by many queries, so the next time I run it after some wait period, I will also get the same exception.

The question is what options do I have to drop all the edges with as little queries as possible?

I was trying to run `q.E().limit(20).drop()` and it works and reports 237.62999999999994 RUs

When I run `q.E().limit(2000).drop()` I get the exception.

The 'g.E().limit(1).drop()' results shows varying RU cost in Azure Data Explorer:

```
Executed: g.E().limit(1).drop() (61.72 RUs)
Executed: g.E().limit(1).drop() (53.14 RUs)
Executed: g.E().limit(1).drop() (61.72 RUs)
Executed: g.E().limit(1).drop() (56 RUs)
```

But constant Request Charge : 546.38

What would be the optimal way to get rid of the edges (in terms of performance and/or in terms of the cost)

Answer (score 1):

When you are running *drop()* query, Cosmos is actually dropping some of edges before it throws 429 "Request rate is large". So, you can retry same query

```
g.E().drop()
```

until you will get empty result (meaning that query resulted in success and all edges were dropped).

I tried out dropping edges from Azure data explorer in CosmosDB, and here is the result (provisioned 400 RU, 329 edges initially):

```
g.E().count() => [329]
g.E().drop() => "Request rate is large"
g.E().count() => [282]
```

In consecutive *drop()* attempts there were dropped 47, 67, 38, 75, 75 and last 27 edges. After 6 attempts I got `[ ]` meaning that all edges were dropped. So retrying until success might be some solution here.